# How can I output numbers formatted a specific way dynamically in a query? Example: 1.234 might need to be 1.2 or 1.234000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

In the database, there is a number (*rawresult*) and a number format (*format*) in a single row.  I want to format the rawresult to how *format* says it should be with a single query.  This is a database that already exists and we can't modify it.

```
Example 1: (rawresult = 1.254; format = 0.0), output should be 1.3
Example 2: (rawresult = 1.254; format = 0.00000), output should be 1.25400
Example 3: (rawresult = 10.254; format = 0.000), output should be 10.254
```

The *format* field can be null, 0, 0.0, have 6 decimal places, or anything in between.  I have no idea how to go about doing this with a single SQL query.  Sometimes, *format* will be null, but that part I can actually handle.  Basically, I need to round it if *format* has less decimal places than *rawresult*, or add trailing 0s if *format* requires more decimal places than *rawresult* has.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is the `FORMAT()` function, but the format must contain a valid .NET Framework format string:

```
SELECT FORMAT([rawresult], [format]) AS [result]
FROM (VALUES
   (1.254,  NULL),
   (1.254,  '0.0'),
   (1.254,  '0.00000'), 
   (10.254, '0.000')
) v ([rawresult], [format])
```

Result:

```
result
-------
1.254
1.3
1.25400
10.254
```

Comment: Yikes.  I was completely overthinking this.  I was looking at getting the length of how many characters were after the . and building off of that.  Such a simple solution.  Thanks.